# how to can I calculate the position of 1 from the long stretch of 0 and 1 code

Tags: python, binary

I have a long stretch of binary code now how can I calculate the position of 1 in the given stretch for example I have two stretches given below:

```
seq1 = 10000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000
       |                    |                    |                    |
       1                    22                   42                   58

seq2 = 10000000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000000000000
       |                     |                    |                    |
       1                    23                    43                  59
```

out put should be like this for first sequence:

```
seq1 1:1 1:22 1:42 1:58
```

for second sequence:

```
seq2 2:1 2:23 2:43 2:59
```

Comment: I think some of your markers are out of place.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started.

```
>>> s='10000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000'
>>> [i+1 for i,ch in enumerate(s) if ch=='1']
[1, 22, 43, 64]
>>>
```

And if you need the rest, here it is:

```
def convertSeq(s, index):
    result = [i+1 for i,ch in enumerate(s) if ch=='1']
    result = ' '.join([str(index)+':'+str(i) for i in result])
    result = 'seq'+str(index)+' '+result
    return result

seq1 = '10000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000000010000000000000000'
seq2 = '10000000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000000000000'

print convertSeq(seq1, 1)
print convertSeq(seq2, 2)
```

Or, if you prefer one-liners:

```
def convertSeq(s, index):
    return 'seq{} {}'.format(
               index,
               ' '.join('{}:{}'.format(index, i+1)
                        for i,ch in enumerate(s)
                        if ch == '1'))
```